How to add an inline record field using Avro in Azure schema registry?
the inline record
{
  "type": "record",
  "name": "Foo",
  "namespace": "com.example",
  "fields": [
    {
        "name": "foo_string",
        "type": "string"
    }
]

}
the record:
{
  "type": "record",
  "name": "Bar",
  "namespace": "com.example",
  "fields": [
      {
        "name": "foo",
        "type": "com.example.Foo"
      }
]

}
Getting an error:
Failed to add schema 'com.example.Bar' with error: {"error":{"code":"InvalidRequest","message":"Avro schema validation failed: Undefined name: com.example.Foo at 'fields[0].type'. TrackingId:ebe0a8ba-d77d-4888-..., ...}}
Just to add, the Foo record is defined and present in the Azure schema registry of course.

You have two options, try them out and let me know. First one is to include the Foo schema definition within the Bar schema directly. Something like this- {   "type": "record",   "name": "Bar",   "namespace": "com.example",   "fields": [     {       "name": "foo",       "type": {         "type": "record",         "name": "Foo",         "fields": [           {             "name": "foo_string",             "type": "string"           }         ]       }     }   ] } and another option is to do separate registration i.e. register Foo schema first then register the Bar schema.

Logic behind my above suggestion is in option2, Foo is registered before Bar, resolving the issue of the Foo type being undefined when trying to register Bar. Atleast what I understood from the error message- Undefined name: com.example.Foo

See it works

I wonder why this question was down-voted. please leave a comment to explain how can I improve the question

As I can see from your error- validation failed: Undefined name: com.example.Foo and as suggested it comments, it means since Foo is not registered before Bar, it is throwing error. To resolve the issue of the Foo type being undefined when trying to register Bar. You can try any of the two-way I suggested in comment. Let's go by option 1 i.e. include the Foo schema definition inline within the Bar schema.
from azure.schemaregistry import SchemaRegistryClient
from azure.identity import DefaultAzureCredential

# Your specifics
SCHEMA_REGISTRY_FQDN = "arkons.servicebus.windows.net"
SCHEMA_GROUP_NAME = "arkoschema"

# Initialize the client
credential = DefaultAzureCredential()
client = SchemaRegistryClient(fully_qualified_namespace=SCHEMA_REGISTRY_FQDN, credential=credential)

# Define Foo schema
foo_schema = '''
{
  "type": "record",
  "name": "Foo",
  "namespace": "arkons.arkoschema",
  "fields": [
    {
      "name": "foo_string",
      "type": "string"
    }
  ]
}
'''

# Register Foo schema
response_foo = client.register_schema(SCHEMA_GROUP_NAME, "Foo", foo_schema, "Avro")
print(f"Registered Foo schema id: {response_foo.id}")

# Define Bar schema with an inline definition of Foo
bar_schema = '''
{
  "type": "record",
  "name": "Bar",
  "namespace": "arkons.arkoschema",
  "fields": [
    {
      "name": "foo",
      "type": {
        "type": "record",
        "name": "Foo",
        "fields": [
          {
            "name": "foo_string",
            "type": "string"
          }
        ]
      }
    }
  ]
}
'''

# Register Bar schema
response_bar = client.register_schema(SCHEMA_GROUP_NAME, "Bar", bar_schema, "Avro")
print(f"Registered Bar schema id: {response_bar.id}")


You can even check the official MS doc once, only difference is they showed with C# example and I did using python.

Validate using an Avro schema when streaming events using Event Hubs .NET SDKs (AMQP)


sadly, it's not really resolving the issue as the inline record may be reused for multiple records. should I duplicate it for each record? and what happens if I need to change the inline record? then I will need to update multiple outer records and hope not to miss anything.

Hmm, what if you use a script to dynamically compose schemas with their dependencies before registering them? Lets say for example, you store your schemas in files and then write a script to read, compose, and register schemas.. Can you give it a try or let me know if you want me to share any sample code for your ease?
